# How do I get my current location using Uber API?

Tags: uber-api

Imagine I am a user/Uber driver, how can I use the Uber API to get my current location and plot the location on the map? I want to track the user on the map. All this to be done using Python API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint [`/requests/current`](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-current) responds with a location object including lat & lng values. You could use these for your mapping feature. Otherwise, there's another method [`/requests/{request_id}/map`](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-map) that responds with a URL to a map provided by the API.

As for Python, [the SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk) provides you the above-mentioned methods:

- [get_current_ride_details](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/uber_rides/client.py#L430)
- [get_ride_map](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/uber_rides/client.py#L516)

Comment: That's only possible when I have a ride, what if I don't . How will I get my location then?

Comment: Well, if you don't have a ride it's up to you to identify the user's location. The Uber API itself is not a location provider in that sense. You'd need to use the underlying technology to get a user's position. For instance, if you're using pure HTML on the front-end, you could obtain the location through [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) features.

Answer (score 0):

Through Python you can their IP address to track their location. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24907340/5817707) question talks about how to use FreeGeoIP to track their location. Using the IP address won't be perfectly accurate, so if you need a more accurate representation, you'll need a way to interact with the GPS system on a device. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797435/get-precise-android-gps-location-in-python) question has an example of using Android and Python together, and agraebe mentioned you can use the [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) features in his comment. [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) looks like a Python IDE for IOS that has a [locations](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/location.html) service. I don't have much experience with these, but I hope some of these resources help.