# Accessing the location of an Android Tablet with Python, from computer

Tags: python, android, gps

Hello there, hope you are all doing well.

For a project, I need to access the location (longitude and latitude) of an Android tablet on Python. However, I do not have a prior experience on that and therefore I do not know how to solve this. Can you show me a possible way to reach and print the location of my Android tablet with a Python script?

The tablet is connected to cellular data for internet.

Comment: let me know if you got an answer.

Comment: @super_ask The answers on this post helped me greatly! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797435/get-precise-android-gps-location-in-python

You need to install QPython 3L on your Android device and write the scripts on the page I mentioned. Works flawlessly!